# If both $\Phi, \neg\phi$ and $\Phi, \psi$ are inconsistent, then $\Phi \vdash \neg(\phi \to \psi)$.

Tags: proof-verification, logic, propositional-calculus

Could someone check whether my solution is okay?

> If both $\Phi, \neg\phi$ and $\Phi, \psi$ are inconsistent, then $\Phi \vdash \neg(\phi \to \psi)$.

[image]

Comment: But in the proof above *inconsistency* is "syntactical"...

Comment: You have correctly considered $\Phi, (\varphi \to \psi)$. From it and the fact that $\Phi \vdash \varphi$ we get, by *modus ponens* : $\Phi, (\varphi \to \psi) \vdash \psi$. This in turn, using the fact that $\Phi \vdash \lnot \psi$, implies that $\Phi, (\varphi \to \psi)$ is inconsistent and we can conclude that $\Phi \vdash \lnot (\varphi \to \psi)$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thank you for helping me prove the forward direction. I am trying to show that the converse of this is also true. I started with assuming $\Phi \vdash \neg (\phi \to \psi)$ and so $\Phi, \phi \to \psi$ is inconsistent. But I am unsure where to go from here to show that both $\Phi, \neg\phi$ and $\Phi, \psi$ are inconsistent...do you have any idea?

Comment: Correct; assume  $Φ⊢¬(ϕ→ψ)$. From it follows : $Φ,ψ ⊢ ¬(ϕ→ψ)$. We have that $\Phi, \psi \vdash (\phi \to \psi)$ and thus we have that $\Phi, \psi$ is inconsistent.

Comment: In the same way, we have $Φ,¬ϕ ⊢ (ϕ→ψ)$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA You're truly the master of logic!!

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA May I ask where $\Phi, \psi \vdash \phi \to \psi$ came from?

Comment: Your questions are about $\vdash$, i.e. *derivability* that means axioms+rules. What proof system are you using ? Natural Deduction ? Hilbert-style ? in Hilbert-style axiom systems for prop calculus a "standard" axiom is $\vdash \psi \to (\phi \to \psi)$. Thus, $\Phi, \psi \vdash (\phi \to \psi)$ by *modus ponens*. For more detials, you have to specify $\vdash$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify that you are assuming the arbitrary valuation function, $\sigma$, shall hold $\Phi$ to be true.

---

Take as given that $\Phi,\neg\phi$ and $\Psi,\psi$ are inconstistent.   Assume that a valuation function, $\sigma$, satisfies $\Phi$ .   That is $\sigma(\Phi)=\mathrm T$.   Therefore $\sigma(\neg\phi)\neq\mathrm T$ and $\sigma(\psi)\neq\mathrm T$ because of the inconsistancies.   In classical logic that is $\sigma(\phi)=\mathrm T$ and $\sigma(\psi)=\mathrm F$.   From that we infer $\sigma(\phi\to\psi)=\mathrm F$, since $\phi\to\psi$ cannot be satisfied when $\phi$ is true but $\psi$ is false.   Therefore there is no evaluation that satisfies both $\Phi$ and $\phi\to\psi$, that is $\Phi,\phi\to\psi$ is inconsistent.   Consequently $\Phi\vDash \neg(\phi\to\psi)$ .

Comment: Wow, you really made a great answer and helped cleared many things! Thanks!